# Creating MS Access Forms with HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ms-access

I am assisting with a local MS Access database and am creating a number of extensive forms. I was wondering if it is possible to create forms via HTML or Javascript (rather than creating them directly within Access) and then use them locally within the database? Has anyone run across anything like  this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No.

More complex answer: you could build a web application, run it on a local webserver, and interface with Access in the application (using ODBC if you go Node or PHP, or using ADO if you go ASP). Then you can insert a web browser control in a form in your Access database, and link it to that application.

Really, if you want to script inside forms, use VBA. It's a little more difficult than HTML and JS, and can do less with visual effects, timers and async processing etc, but it runs locally inside Access and can do way more that way.

Comment: That is what I figured, but thought I would check and see. Thanks for the input.